# How to print another version or type of alphabet 'a'?

Tags: css, fonts, photoshop

[screeenshot of facebook logo which I want to make in Photoshop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrSQW.png)
I want to make facebook logo like in login form. In photoshop i tried tahoma font but it shows 'a' version. I want to use other version. Also, i want to use them in texts in web-page.

Comment: Find a font that has the "A" you want and maybe convert that font into a usable web font.

Comment: If i will use another font it will be not similar to facebook logo. It will not be what i want to do. And, tell any fonts which have got that type of logo?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe use an image.

Comment: Two options: firstly i can use screenshot to do that. Secondly, i can make my own image in Photoshop, but for that again i need font family name.

Comment: No, use an image without any fonts. Use an <img> tag. It doesn't require a font family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the font online and convert it to a usable font in Photoshop.
Filson Soft from Mostardesign has the specific "a" you're looking for.

Comment: I know many fonts like Lucida italic and Lucida Calligraphy which have got specific "a" but they don't look like the Lucida which is used in fb. That's the problem. I googled and it says that font is Lucida but i am not getting the exact font. btw, thank you.